# google checkout digital products

Tags: html, payment, google-checkout

Basically I want a functionality to download code mywebsite.

I checked following link for google checkout digital products.
https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=39011

I created buy now button for digital product from sandbox using this link.HTML code redirects me to google checkouts as usual.

But it does not give me any download link anywhere after payment. ??

```
 <form action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/859574590497884" id="BB_BuyButtonForm" method="post" name="BB_BuyButtonForm" target="_top">
<input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="mycode"/>
<input name="item_description_1" type="hidden" value="this item is all about my code"/>
<input name="item_quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1"/>
<input name="item_price_1" type="hidden" value="1251.0"/>
<input name="item_currency_1" type="hidden" value="USD"/>
<input name="shopping-cart.items.item-1.digital-content.description" type="hidden" value="Please read this instructions.."/>
<input name="shopping-cart.items.item-1.digital-content.url" type="hidden" value="http://www.xxxxxxxx.in/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/20110929034224791156.pdf"/>
<input name="_charset_" type="hidden" value="utf-8"/>
<input alt="" src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/buy.gif?merchant_id=859574590497884&amp;w=117&amp;h=48&amp;style=white&amp;variant=text&amp;loc=en_US" type="image"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Checkout offer a digital delivery solution, with various options for providing access to the digital content.

Please be aware that credit card transactions are authorized and charged AFTER the user places the order. Depending on how valuable the content is, you may want to hold off providing the URL to the download content until payment is guaranteed.

More details in this doc:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Digital_Delivery.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `continue_url`

```
<input type="hidden" name="continue_url" value="http://www.example.com/download"/>
```

Comment: thanks John for replying...user will be able to download the product everytime he want. right ? is there any way by which it is accessible only one time...

Comment: That would require you implementing some kind of control on your end. Usually this is done by appending a unique token to the download URL and when it is pulled by the user it is then marked as downloaded. Then the next time someone tries to use that URL you can check the database to see if it is valid, and if it isn't it can be rejected.

Comment: See [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/how-do-i-prevent-users-from-accessing-a-page-more-then-once/11238#11238) for more information on this